# Reading text lines,sorting them and writing them into a new text file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, notepad

i have been struggling in writing a program that would solve a particular problem for me, i have not used c++ since years now which has made it hard for me to complete the program in time.
I have text data like following:

10929  12490 1023 12 29 10 92 96 100 10
             10929  12290 1023 10 29 10 95 90  90 10
             10929  12190 1023 12 29 10 93 91  80 12
             10929  12590 1023 10 29 10 97 90  70 10
             10929  12490 1023 12 29 10 92 96 100 11
             10929  12290 1023 10 29 10 95 90  90 10
             10929  12190 1023 12 29 10 93 91  80 10
             10929  12590 1023 10 29 10 97 90  70 10

I need to sort the data so that the new file would have all the 100's together and consequent, same for the 90's, 80's and 70's ( note the second column from the right).

my main problem so far is saving each single line to an array of strings to make them easy to sort, the form i had in mind is: array[line_data, line_number]

Any help on the issue would be appreciated, Thank you for your time

Comment: Is this a homework?,also please format the question a little bit. looks messy

Comment: No it is not a homework, these are fictional samples of wind reading that i have been taking for a while now (did not paste real data because lines are too long ). I want to get my building committee to aprove installing wind turbines....I just improved the format a little, hope its clearer like this.

Comment: it would really worth to tell us, how big the dataset is that you want to scan. If there is a chance to overflow your RAM you should probably apply your sort algorithm by hand, reading and writing just the lines you compare. If you don't have that problem this approach just blows your code and kills your processing speed. So giving us a dimension is quite a point here.

Comment: The data files are between 1 - 150 MB of notepad text. most of them are just a bit over 10 MB though.

Answer (score 0):

1. read file line by line. you can use fgets for this
2. add every line to a list (ex std:list) that contains string and the value
   (sscanf_s("%d %d %d ...") to get second value from right)
3. sort using std:stable_sor
4. write everything to output file

Sample

```
struct tagITEM {char*   szLine;  int    iSort;}ITEM, *pITEM;

std::list<ITEM> lItems;

inline bool lt_ItemCmp(ITEM& c1, ITEM& c2) { return c1.iLine < c2.iLine; }

std::stable_sort(lItems.begin(), lItems.end(), lt_ItemCmp);
```

note that the code above was not tested

Comment: I need to sort it according to line number because in some places the columns are not separated by spaces. also in some lines there is data values of 100 or 90 value..
Scanning according to location in text line is possible as well since they are always constant ( they always have 20 numbers and spaces before them for example )

Comment: sscanf_s to get number as int. std:stable_sort receive a sort function that will sort according to that int

Comment: i will look into struct and list, ill let you know what happens from there

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the data be stored in an array like "array[line_data, line_number]" you can do this:

1. open the file using an ifstream
2. use std::getline to read each line
3. save the data from getline into a container

so, the reading would look like this, given you use an std::ifstream named "file" and a container named storage:

```
std::string str;
std::list<std::string> storage; 
//or std::vector<std::string>, depends on how much you have to read in

while(std::getline(file,str))
{
     storage.push_back(str);
}
```

With this, in storage[0] would be the first line of your textfile.

Comment: Looks very nice, but i need a little more info please:
having storage as a string gives me an error ( cannot convert parameter from string to char ) , also what is str intended for? i put a string type there

Comment: str is an instance of std::string used by std::getline to store the line in, storage is a std container, such as std::vector, std::list. I will extend my answer in a few seconds

Comment: I see, i have to read in about 150 MBs of text in some cases, i can divide them down to 10MBs , in this case i use std::vector<std::string> correct?

Comment: yes, 10 MB is still a good size for a std::vector. Just when it gets to really big data, you might want to switch to a list (that is, however, no problem at all), since a vector would require a big chunk of free ram whereas a list would only regquire many small chunks.

Comment: However, a list can be sorted faster than a vector.

Comment: Sweet, All went smooth with the reading. However trying to write is giving me an error, i did it in following manner:
file_out<<sotrage[i]
where i would be a variable that selects the line number
error is: binary '[' : 'std::list<_Ty>' does not define this operator

Comment: ah, my bad, list doesn't have an [] operator, sorry for that. But what exactly do you want to archive? Iterating over all elements?

Comment: I want to put line numbers together, such as:
line 1,5,9,13,17 consequent
line 2,6,10,14,18 consequent
line 3,7,11,15,19...
line 4,8,12,16,20...

Comment: Then, you can either use std::advance to jump through the list, [here is how you use it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/). There's an example with list on that site as well. Or, you can use a std::list<std::string>::iterator and a counter variable to iterate through the list and use the modulo operator to calculate which lines have to be put together.